# Is it possible to lock USB port to used only for printing?

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I want to block all the USB ports in a computer to alloow only printing through them. I have been able to block it through the registry, but other devices, not only printers, are able to work in that ports. Is there any way to allow only printing in a USB port?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about restricting all but printing, but this may be of interest to you:

http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/windows/disable_usb_sticks

I guess it could be adapted to be applied to any driver files you like in theory.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)